# How to fetch property values using attribute from multiple entities in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have three entities like this.

Employee:
id
name

EmployeeDepartment:
id
departmentID
employeeID

Department:
id
name

Employee<<---->EmployeeDepartment<---->>Department

suppose Employee and Department has a Many-to-Many Relationship,
I want to get all employee names in "Accounting" department?

If I use SQL query, I will simply use:
**select employee.name from Employee, EmployeeDepartment, Department where employee.id = employeeDepartment.employeeID and Department.id = EmployeeDepartment.departmentID and Department.name = 'Accounting'**

However, how can I do the same thing in Core Data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Data is an object graph manager, not a relational database, so trying to force it into a relational DB mode will lead to pain. Your EmployeeDepartment entity is a perfect example of that; you need it in a relational DB to implement the many to many relationship between Employee and Department, but in Core Data it's not necessary at all. Instead, just give Employee a `departments` property and Department an `employees` property, and then add to-many relationships between the two entities.

Now, if you want to get all the employees in Accounting, you execute a fetch request for entity Department with a predicate that matches Accounting. Once you have that object, you can simply access its `employees` property to get the list of employees.

Comment: since entity department consist of many employees, there are many department objects that contain the same department.name but with different department.employees. If there is ten employees in Accounting department, are there ten objects in entity Department with the same name "Accounting"?

Comment: Sorry -- missed the many-to-many relationship. So an employee can belong to more than one department at a time? It'd seem like there should be a one-to-many relationship: a department can have many employees, but any given employee has only one department. To answer your question, though... no, if there are ten employees in Accounting, you still only have one Accounting dept. The value of the `employees` property is a set containing all the employees of that department.

Comment: Sometime an employee will have more than one department, as he may be a manager with manage more than one department. 

Well, there is a difficulty for me to have a property 'employees' which is a set. I use the GUI builder to add attribute in xcode. It only allows me to use Integer,String,Date,etc... 

So, are you suggesting I should give up that builder?

Comment: No, not at all. Just make the property "to-many" by selecting the relationship and checking the "To-Many Relationship" checkbox in the inspector.

Comment: Wow, I can see `NSSet` now, after I generated the NSManagedObject SubClass. I see what you mean now. You are suggesting that both object maintains a list of related objects to create Many To Many Relationship.